# StepVerifier.Step.then(Runnable) is not invoked

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have some test, which poll some table and push each record into stream. Initially table is empty. Firstly I insert single record to table, than I create Flux:

```
Flux<Record> flux = Flux.create(emitter -> {
        while (!emitter.isCancelled()) {
            //Fetch all records from table and push each record to stream
            jdbTemplate.query(sql, rs -> {
                emitter.next(Record.from(rs));
            });
        }
    });
```

Finally I try to test this Flux with the StepVerifier:

```
StepVerifier.create(flux).
            expectNext(record1). //Expect record inserted by first statement
            then(() -> {
                //Insert record to table
            }).
            expectNext(record2).
            thenCancel().
            verify();
```

Unexpectedly, the Runnable specified in **then()** method is not invoked and test run infinitely.
How I can fix this problem?

Comment: does the `while` loop ever actually exit? I think the create lambda hogs the thread, and the test code has no CPU cycle to execute on. Try chaining a `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())` after `flux` within the `create()`

Comment: Yes, `while` loop is finished. Actually, `Runnable` in `then()` is skipped. I already used `subscribeOn` as alternative approach of this test and it works fine:

Comment: The body of your create is blocking (JdbcTemplate) inside a `while` loop. You need to isolate blocking code like that, so using `subscribeOn` is the correct way to go.

Comment: Yes, is blocking, but records are pushed to stream during iteration against ResultSet:
           `rs -> {
                emitter.next(Record.from(rs));
            }`

Answer (score 0):

Following the [Project Reactor Reference](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#producing.create) I think you need to add a call to `emitter.complete()` after the loop:

```
Flux<Record> flux = Flux.create(emitter -> {

     //Fetch all records from table and push each record to stream
     jdbcTemplate.query(sql, rs -> {
         if (!emitter.isCancelled()) {
             emitter.next(Record.from(rs));
          } 
     });

    emitter.complete();
});
```

My guess is, `then()` expects the completion signal from the previous operation, which is never emitted by `Flux.create()`.

**Edit:** Corrected typo. Also, can you try without the while loop? I guess the check for cancelation should be in the callback, as in the updated code fragment.

Comment: FluxSink interface doesn't have method close. The completion of stream is triggered by invocation of `thenCancel()` method but actually this method is not reached.